# Blazor SessionStorage - Itens returning with escape character

Tags: escaping, blazor, session-storage

In my Blazor App I'm saving some information (It is working as intended, I can see them on my browser and they are well formated) in Session Storage as such:

```
await _sessionStorage.SetItemAsync("userCredentials", loginUser.UserCredentials);
```

[image]

But when try to access them from a component:

```
@inject Blazored.SessionStorage.ISessionStorageService sessionStorage;
...
@code{
...
    string myCrendentials = await sessionStorage.GetItemAsStringAsync("userCredentials");
...
}
```

The result will be `"\"111\""`
[image]

Comment: I would first of all try using consistent API calls - `SetItemAsStringAsync` and `GetItemAsStringAsync` , not the mixture you have now - as one involves JSON serialisation, while the other doesn't.

Comment: @MisterMagoo That solved it, tnx. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first of all try using consistent API calls

- `SetItemAsStringAsync` and `GetItemAsStringAsync`

With the mixture of calls you have now - one involves JSON serialisation, while the other doesn't.

Edit: extra explanation

When you call SetItemAsync and pass it a string, it serializes the string to JSON and stores the JSON in session storage. The JSON will include quotes : "Test"

If you retrieve this session data using GetItemAsStringAsync, it will return the JSON you stored earlier as a string : "Test"

When you call SetItemAsStringAsync and pass it a string, it simply stores the string in session storeage. This string will not include quotes : Test